# c# Regex question

Tags: c#, regex, twitter

I have a problem dealing with the @ symbol in `Regex`, I am trying to remove @sometext 
from a text string can't seem to find anywhere where it uses the @ as a literal. I have tried myself but doesn't remove the word from the string. Any ideas?

```
public string removeAtSymbol(string input)
{
    Regex findWords = new Regex(______);//Find the words like "@text"
    Regex[] removeWords;

    string test = input; 
    MatchCollection all = findWords.Matches(test);
    removeWords = new Regex[all.Count];
    int index = 0;
    string[] values = new string[all.Count];

    YesOutputBox.Text = " you got here";

    foreach (Match m in all) //List all the words
    {
        values[index] = m.Value.Trim();
        index++;
        YesOutputBox.Text = YesOutputBox.Text + " " + m.Value;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < removeWords.Length; i++)
    {
        removeWords[i] = new Regex(" " + values[i]);

        // If the words appears more than one time
        if (removeWords[i].Matches(test).Count > 1)
        {
            removeWords[i] = new Regex(" " + values[i] + " ");
            test = removeWords[i].Replace(test, " "); //Remove the first word.
        }
    }

    return test;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the rest of your code works? What's the regex you're using? @ should be usable as a literal.

Comment: Test out your regex here first: http://regexhero.net/   If it works...then test your code...

Comment: Are you trying to match twitter usernames or anything that has `@`, including emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all occurences of `"@sometext"` from string `test` via the method

```
Regex.Replace(test, "@sometext", "")
```

or for any word starting with `"@"` you can use

```
Regex.Replace(test, "@\\w+", "")
```

If you need specifically a separate word (i.e. nothing like `@comp` within `tom@comp.com`) you may preceed the regex with a special word boundary (`\b` does not work here):

```
Regex.Replace(test, "(^|\\W)@\\w+", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^\s@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)
```

as the regex to recognize Twitter usernames.

Answer (score 0):

Regex to remove @something from this string: I want to remove @something from this string.

```
var regex = new Regex("@\\w*");
string result = regex.Replace(stringWithAt, "");
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That regex would also match `someemail@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck applying this pattern:

```
\B@\w+
```

This will match any string starting with an @ character that contains alphanumeric characters, plus some linking punctuation like the underscore character, if it does not occur on a boundary between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters.

The result of executing this code:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(
    @"@This1 @That2_thing this2@3that @the5Others @alpha@beta@gamma",
    @"\B@\w+", 
    @"redacted");
```

is the following string:

```
redacted redacted this2@3that redacted redacted@beta@gamma
```

---

If this question *is* Twitter-specific, then Twitter provides an [open source library](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/introducing-open-source-twitter-text.html) that helps capture Twitter-specific entities like links, mentions and hashtags.  [This java file](https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-java/blob/master/src/com/twitter/Regex.java) contains the code defining the regular expressions that Twitter uses, and [this yml file](https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-conformance/blob/master/autolink.yml) contains test strings and expected outcomes of many unit tests that exercise the regular expressions in the Twitter library.

Twitter's mention-matching pattern (extracted from their library, modified to remove unnecessary capture groups, and edited to make sense in the context of a replacement) is shown below.  The match should be performed in a case-insensitive manner.

```
(^|[^a-z0-9_])[@\uFF20][a-z0-9_]{1,20}
```

Here is an example which reproduces the results of the first replacement in my answer:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(
    @"@This1 @That2_thing this2@3that @the5Others @alpha@beta@gamma", 
    @"(^|[^a-z0-9_])[@\uFF20][a-z0-9_]{1,20}", 
    @"$1redacted",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note the need to include the substitution `$1` since the first capture group can't be directly converted into an atomic zero-width assertion.